# Curly braces inside \lstlisting incorrectly displayed in tabularx

Tags: listings, tabularx

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage {tabularx}

\begin{document}
Expectation:
\begin{table}[l]
    abc \lstinline[]${def}$ ghi \\
    \lstinline[]$abc {def} ghi$ \\
\end{table}

Found:
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
        abc \lstinline[]${def}$ ghi \\
        \lstinline[]$abc {def} ghi$ \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to use `lstinline` with curly braces inside a `tabularx` table, but it leads to weird problems.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use verb-like commands in the argument of another command, and for technical reasons, that includes the body of `tabularx`, so:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\newsavebox\zzz
\newsavebox\zzzb
\begin{document}
Expectation:
\begin{table}%??[l]
    abc \lstinline[]${def}$ ghi \\
    \lstinline[]$abc {def} ghi$ \\
\end{table}

Found:
\begin{table}
\begin{lrbox}{\zzz}\lstinline[]${def}$\end{lrbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\zzzb}\lstinline[]$abc {def} ghi$\end{lrbox}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
        abc \usebox\zzz\ ghi \\
         \usebox\zzzb
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```